# Is it possible to use setInterval and geolocation information at the same time?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, setinterval

I created a jsfiddle to show that when `setInterval` is used combined with `getcurrentposition` it stops working. The jsfiddle is very intuitive , the `Math.random()` function was only used to show that the `setInterval` is overall working. Of course the `position.coords.latitude` won't work in the fiddle, but if you try it in a website enviroment it won't work either. The end purpose of the question is to fetch the user geolocation with a regular interval. Thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/hYFzB/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you intended to call `getLocation()` in your `setInterval()` instead of `showPosition()`.

[Updated fiddle works](http://jsfiddle.net/hYFzB/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the geoLocation method before trying to fetch the position. Your call in the interval should be changed to:

```
var int=self.setInterval(getLocation, 1000);
```

No function wrapper is required if the function does not take any arguments.